Error : Duplicate class com.facebook.jni and Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader
I am trying to solve duplicate error while doing android setup. i tried many solutions, not getting any result. You can check the steps and general configuration i performed.
General setup:

Android emulator -34.2.15

Android SDk build tool- 35

Node version-16.15.0

npm version-8.5.5

React version- "18.2.0"

React native version- "0.72.5"

Android studio- Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1

Gradle version-8.0.1

Gradle plugin version-7.4.2

java - 17.0.10 2024-01-16 LTS


Set up environment variables:
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk ,
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home 
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator 
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools 
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin 
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

Project setup:

Installing Dependencies -> npm install --legacy-peer-deps
Update react-native-secure-storage Gradle File ->

    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
    
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 34
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
     }
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
     }
    
    dependencies {
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    implementation 'com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2@aar'
     }
    
    afterEvaluate { project -
    
    task androidJavadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += files(android.bootClasspath)
       }
    
    android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    def name = variant.name.capitalize()
    task "jar${name}"(type: Jar, dependsOn: variant.javaCompile) {
    from variant.javaCompile.destinationDir
             }     }
        }
    
     }



Sync Gradle [till this step successfully completed]
Run the code -npx react-native run-android [Here we are getting dDuplicate error.]

Error i am getting
Duplicate class com.facebook.jni.DestructorThread found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-fbjni-0.3.0-runtime (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.3.0)
Duplicate class com.facebook.jni.DestructorThread$1 found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-fbjni-0.3.0-runtime (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.3.0)
Duplicate class com.facebook.jni.DestructorThread$Destructor found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-fbjni-0.3.0-runtime (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.3.0)
Duplicate class com.facebook.jni.DestructorThread$DestructorList found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-fbjni-0.3.0-runtime (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.3.0)
Duplicate class com.facebook.jni.DestructorThread$DestructorStack found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-fbjni-0.3.0-runtime (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.3.0)
Duplicate class com.facebook.jni.DestructorThread$Terminus found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-fbjni-0.3.0-runtime (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.3.0)
Duplicate class com.facebook.jni.HybridClassBase found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-fbjni-0.3.0-runtime (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.3.0)
Duplicate class com.facebook.proguard.annotations.KeepGettersAndSetters found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-react-android-0.72-debug.5-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.72.5)
Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.Api18TraceUtils found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-soloader-0.10.5-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5)
Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-soloader-0.10.5-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5)
Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource$ApkUnpacker found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-soloader-0.10.5-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5)
Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-soloader-0.10.5-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5)
Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.DoNotOptimize found in modules jetified-annotation-0.10.5 (com.facebook.soloader:annotation:0.10.5) and jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2)
Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.Elf32_Dyn found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-soloader-0.10.5-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5)
Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.Elf32_Ehdr found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-soloader-0.10.5-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5)
Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.Elf32_Phdr found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-soloader-0.10.5-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5)
Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.Elf32_Shdr found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-soloader-0.10.5-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5)
Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.Elf64_Dyn found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-soloader-0.10.5-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5)
Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.Elf64_Ehdr found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-soloader-0.10.5-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5)
Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.Elf64_Phdr found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-soloader-0.10.5-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5)
Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.Elf64_Shdr found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-soloader-0.10.5-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5)
Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.ExoSoSource found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-soloader-0.10.5-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5)
Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.ExoSoSource$1 found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-soloader-0.10.5-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5)
Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.ExoSoSource$ExoUnpacker found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-soloader-0.10.5-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5)
Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.ExoSoSource$ExoUnpacker$FileBackedInputDsoIterator found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-soloader-0.10.5-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5)
Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.ExoSoSource$FileDso found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-soloader-0.10.5-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5)
Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.ExtractFromZipSoSource found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-soloader-0.10.5-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5)
Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.ExtractFromZipSoSource$1 found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-soloader-0.10.5-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5)
Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.ExtractFromZipSoSource$ZipDso found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-soloader-0.10.5-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5)
Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.ExtractFromZipSoSource$ZipUnpacker found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-soloader-0.10.5-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5)
Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.ExtractFromZipSoSource$ZipUnpacker$ZipBackedInputDsoIterator found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-soloader-0.10.5-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5)
Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.FileLocker found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-soloader-0.10.5-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5)
Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.MergedSoMapping found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-soloader-0.10.5-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5)
Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.MinElf found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-soloader-0.10.5-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5)
Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.MinElf$ElfError found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-soloader-0.10.5-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5)
Duplicate class com.facebook.soloader.NativeLibrary found in modules jetified-conceal-2.0.2-runtime (com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2) and jetified-soloader-0.10.5-runtime (com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5)

Here you can see the depedency in build.gradle(:app) file
dependencies {
// The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")

    implementation("androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0")
    
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }
    
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }

I have tried the solution
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy {
force 'com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2'
force 'com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.3.0'
}
}

dependencies {
// The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")

    implementation("androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0")
    
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }
    
    implementation('com.facebook.react:react-android:0.74.5') {
        exclude group: 'com.facebook.conceal', module: 'conceal'
        exclude group: 'com.facebook.fbjni', module: 'fbjni'
    }
    
    implementation('com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.facebook.fbjni', module: 'fbjni'
    }
    implementation('com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.6.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.facebook.conceal', module: 'conceal'
    }
    
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }

}


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

here I am getting a Duplicate class error while running the Android app
